# Постоянная проверка файлов в директории Android

Tags: java, android

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой: мне нужно каким-то образом проверять файлы в директории на внутренней памяти Android-устройства через определённое кол-во времени, и если появляются новые, то читать их при помощи `BufferedReader`. Буду очень признателен вашей помощи

Comment: с какой периодичностью? раз в месяц/день/час.минуту

Answer (score 0):

1. повторять через определенное время можно так:

   ```
   private Runnable repeatativeTaskRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new 
   Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new 
   Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

     //DO YOUR THINGS
    }
   };
   ```

Чтобы запустить повтор и установить задержку:

```
private Handler taskHandler = new NonLeakyHandler(FlashActivity.this);
taskHandler.postDelayed(repeatativeTaskRunnable , DELAY_MILLIS);
```

2.для того чтобы сканировать папку на наличие новых файлов надо:

-прочитать названия всех файлов

-если файл уже есть в массиве с названиями файлов то пропускаем,а если нет то записываем его название в массив и читаем его.

3.читать файл можно так:

```
void readFile() {
try {
  // открываем поток для чтения
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      openFileInput(FILENAME)));
  String str = "";
  // читаем содержимое
  while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, str);
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```